# CRM 2013 Business Rule Debugging

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have CRM 2013 Business Rules that are working in an environment (1 server) and sometimes does not work on the other (multiple servers).

I tried tracing but did not show any related issues.

I am wondering if there is a way to debug a Business Rule in CRM?

Comment: Hi Nick, a business rule is just adding javascript to the form. You should be able to debug them using the browser debugging tools.

Comment: Hi Draiden, Thank you for your comment. How can I debug JavaScript without knowing the function name? Does the Business Rule act as a JavaScript function? If so how can I get the name?

Comment: This label Mscrm.BusinessRulesScript.Initialize that should do the trick.

Comment: Frankly speaking I don't like business rules, since I'm a developer i prefer to put down javascript

Comment: You just need to find the entry point of those functions, I will look at them as soon as i will have more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find Mscrm.BusinessRulesScript.Initialize(s). After opening the CRM form press F12 to get the debugging tool opened then select Script then click Start Debugging and search for Mscrm.BusinessRulesScript.Initialize and I found them under Dynamic Scripts -> Script Block (154).

Comment: Can you please put a not on how you identified the dynamic script? It can be a challenging task since you can have hundreds on them.

Comment: You CANNOT identify the name in advance since it is dynamic and changes every time. You need to search inside the F12 tool when start debugging and it will find the name for you.

Comment: That was for sure, but maybe you found a smart way to do it, thanks for the reply.